# Why Rails uses RUBY_EVAL to define methods?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, oop, dynamic

I was reading Crafting Rails Applications book and got my hands on the Rails source code. There I found some RUBY_EVAL examples that made me think: why do they did it?

action_controller/metal/renderers.rb uses it to compose the body for _write_render_options and define _handle_render_options methods.

```
def _write_render_options
  renderers = _renderers.map do |name, value|
    <<-RUBY_EVAL
      if options.key?(:#{name})
        _process_options(options)
        return _render_option_#{name}(options.delete(:#{name}), options)
      end
    RUBY_EVAL
  end

  class_eval <<-RUBY_EVAL, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
    def _handle_render_options(options)
      #{renderers.join}
    end
  RUBY_EVAL
end
```

_render_option_#{name} methods are defined on the fly as well

```
RENDERERS = {}
def self.add(key, &block)
  define_method("_render_option_#{key}", &block)
  RENDERERS[key] = block
  All._write_render_options
end
```

It seems to me that there were alternatives to eval. Why not just keep those &blocks associated with the keys under a hash? So when calling _handle_render_options we would pick the right block and eval it? Why building a method body with lots of if's which is inefficient, right?

Haven't got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why building a method body with lots of if's which is inefficient, right?

Well, it isn't inefficient. If you have a hash of options on runtime, as you described, you'd have to loop the hash at runtime checking each available renderer in the list of options. The current implementation basically unfolds this loop into a bunch of clauses. Therefore, it will actually be faster than having the loop at runtime.

Actually, the whole reason the code looks like it does now is performance. That's why we don't keep the blocks around since compiling them to methods is actually faster. However, the Ruby VM/GC changes every release and it may no longer be true or the difference between the approaches may not matter anymore, but when it was originally written, it did.

Comment: Why not use `define_method` everywhere?

Comment: `define_method` is slightly more expensive because it keeps the binding that needs to be activated when there is call. I am unsure though if this is still relevant in the latest Ruby releases, likely not.